# Reverting changes in .bash_profile?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I wanted to delete Ruby and RVM so I removed the path from my .bash_profile. Then I deleted the whole rvm folder using `rm`.

Now there shouldn't be anything calling RVM, and this error message keeps arising if I do `cd ..` to go back to directory.

```
-bash: /Users/doris/.rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
```

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: why not just use `rvm implode`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already did this, but just to be sure...

Have a look in your .bash_profile file.  Make sure you removed this line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell     session *as a function*
```

Then make sure you logout and login again.